# Install Ubuntu on Asus P4S8X-X

Tags: ati, asus

I have a very ancient Pc, for which I'd like to install
Ubuntu.

Motherboard is Asus P4S8X-X and graphics Card is Asus Radeon HD4650-AGP 1GB.
I have heard that graphics card installation could cause problems. Sound card is Sounblaster 32 bit.

Is it possible to get Ubuntu installed on this ancient machine at all?

If so, could you point me to installation instructions.

My main usage is to Run databas an programmin with Java.

I have very limited experince from Ubuntu, mainly from 12.04 version.

Thanks in advance and Greetings from Finland

Comment: How much RAM does your computer have?

Comment: I have 2GB of RAM

Comment: Minimum systems requirements for the latest version of Ubuntu is at 768MB RAM and at least 5GB free disk space on the hard drive. If your computer has a Pentium 4 processor you need to install the 32-bit Ubuntu, NOT the 64-bit. If your computer has a Pentium 4 processor, you might prefer Xubuntu 32-bit instead of Ubuntu for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use **Lubuntu** or **Xubuntu**.They are lightweight and appropriate for older hardware.

Installation

- download the iso file.
- mount it on an dvd/usb drive.
- boot from the usb/dvd by selecting appropriate option in **boot menu**.Then just follow the instructions.

Comment: I have great experience with LXLE, a Ubuntu-derived distro which is specifically aimed at older computers.

Comment: @Piskvor LXLE is good, but not official derivative of Ubuntu.It also has problem with localization.There is an nice review of LXLE in **FCM issue 81** if anyone needs to compare it with Lubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. (Haven't noticed any localization problems  myself; but I haven't tested it thoroughly, and apparently YMMV)